# integration of ck editor in vue js

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to integrate ckeditor with vue js in my application. Everything is working fine but when i click on submit button, all the data is saved in database and all fields are empty.
but in this case , i am not able to edit the ck-editor if i refresh or change the dom and again come to same page then working fine.
I think it needs to re-binding of ckeditor but I am not sure how we can do it.
I followed this link -> https://vuejsexamples.com/ckeditor-using-for-vue-js-2/
to integrate the ck-editor and also using js file of ckeditor on index page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the Form which you are using is submitted by the browser - native html behaviour. To avoid that, the input field with type submit should look like (both @submit.prevent so as @click.prevent):

```
 <form @submit.prevent="">
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="ok" @click.prevent="" />
 </form>
```

Comment: I am not using form tag, simply using div and on click of button saving data in table.